# Qiskit: Get approximate execution time

Tags: qiskit, programming

The IBMQ web interface shows both queue position and an approximate execution time for every pending job (see image below). Is there a way to retrieve this information via Qiskit? I know that `qiskit.providers.ibmq.job.IBMQJob` has a `queue_position()` method, but what about the approximate execution time?

Thanks in advance!

[image: IBMQ Job table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for the actual time spent on the device, `time_taken` mentioned by @KAJ226b is the right attribute.

If you're looking for the estimated job completion time, you can use the `queue_info()` method of `IBMQJob`. It gives you the estimated start/completion time, job priority, and queue position (if available).

Comment: `QueueInfo.estimated_start_time` is exactly what I was looking for. Perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
backend=provider.get_backend('The backend that you used') #Example: 'ibmq_santiago' 
job = backend.retrieve_job('Put your JOB ID here') #You can get this on the ibmq web interface 
job_result = job.result()
job_approx_execution_time = job_result.time_taken
```

Note for the Job ID, you can see and copy it from the ibmq web interface:
[image]

Also make sure you use the same provider to extract your backend. This shouldn't be a problem if you only have one provider which is the case for most people. But there are cases where you have different providers, which essentially allocate the different machines you can use.

Comment: `job_result.time_taken` (apparently) does not exist anymore. It seems it has been replaced with `job.metrics()` under the `"usage"` key. Is it possible for you to update your answer please? :)

Answer (score 0):

For those looking to get up to date on this, as the approved answer will change over time, be sure to check the documentation that states this clearly:

- Monitor a Job: https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/run/monitor-job
- Estimate job run time: https://docs.quantum.ibm.com/run/estimate-job-run-time