# queueinfo() module in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I want to know how to use queueinfo() module in IBM Qiskit. When I type job.QueueInfo(), it says "QueueInfo" is not defined. How to import it? I'm trying to use queueinfo() to know the time of start of execution of quantum circuit. Please help.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about quantum computing (much as "How to import queueinfo from astroplan?" would not be a question about astronomy).

Comment: Dear Adam Zalcman, I'm really unaware of using the IBM Quantum Computer program module called "queueinfo()", such questions have been answered before but not specifically on the procedure of implementation but as a kind of information, see for example: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17768/qiskit-get-approximate-execution-time

Answer (score 1):

I believe the method you are looking for is [this one](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.job.IBMQJob.queue_info.html#qiskit.providers.ibmq.job.IBMQJob.queue_info). You use it just by doing `job.queue_info()`. However, if the thing you are looking for is just the time of the beginning of execution of your circuit maybe [this is enough](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.job.IBMQJob.creation_date.html#qiskit.providers.ibmq.job.IBMQJob.creation_date). You use it the same way.

Anyway, you should check [the documentation page](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.job.IBMQJob.html#qiskit.providers.ibmq.job.IBMQJob) to see exactly what you can have and what you're looking for.

Comment: Dear Lena, Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: @CSSYK you should accept this answer.